# Chat messages are not delivered to a user recent logged until he opens chat activity

Tags: android, applozic

I have been testing **Applozic** for a few days, and everything works perfectly. But I've encountered a strange behavior:

- a recently logged user can not receive messages until he opens the
  ConversationActivity, after that (with ConversationActivity on screen
  or not), all new messages are shown like notificacionts or using
  `MessageDatabaseService(context).getTotalUnreadCount()` p.e.
- If the recently user logged not enter in ConversationActivity, all
  new messages appears like not delivered in dashboard, and any request
  like `getTotalUnreadCount()` or `getLatestMessagesGroupByPeople()`
  will return no results. In this cases the app is active and I have
  check that logout is not called

I hope I explained well, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done GCM or FCM setup and updated the GCM or FCM server key in Applozic dashboard  under Action-->edit-->Select push notification tab and update GCM server key  ?

Comment: Thanks, now it works